# Can't install conduit on Windows

Tags: haskell, cabal, conduit

Having trouble installing conduit on a Windows 7 box, 32-bit. I am unfamiliar with Share.h. What windows C library am I missing here?

```
$ cabal install conduit
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring conduit-1.0.9...
Building conduit-1.0.9...
Preprocessing library conduit-1.0.9...
Win32File.hsc:32:19: fatal error: Share.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
compiling dist\dist-sandbox-21799537\build\System\Win32File_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
```

Comment: From a little googling, it looks like this is something that comes with mingw. Have you got that installed?

Comment: @DanielWagner yes, that appears to have fixed it. Now cannot install hsopenssl (not hopenssl) with minigw though.

Comment: @DanielWagner nvm got it. cabal install hsopenssl --extra-include-dirs="C:/OpenSSL-Win32/outinc" --extr a-lib-dirs="C:/OpenSSL-Win32"

Comment: If you solved the problem, good etiquette is to write up exactly what you did to fix it as an answer, then mark that answer as accepted.

Comment: so what is the answer?

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ install mingw was the answer to the original question.